# Create a random number in a range from a fixed and variable denominator

Tags: php, random

From today's date in time() format and username I need to create a random number between `900 (15 minutes)` and `7200 (3 hours)` valid for **24 hours**.

```
$timestamps = '1583334801'; // 03/04/2020
$username = 'donaldtrump';
```

This random number cannot be stored, so it must be calculated several times a day, the result must be identical for **24 hours**.

Do you have an idea on how to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution give share @MultiSuperFreek**

> I'd use a seed based on the day and the username, something like this:

```
$time = '1583334801';
$user = 'donaldtrump';

$time = date('mdY', $time);

$seed = $time . $user;

$intseed = intval(substr(md5($seed), 0, 8), 16);

srand($intseed);
$random = rand(900, 7200);
var_dump($random);
```

Comment: Really Good Answer. I appreciate with you.